# rails get method name from string and then pass arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Folks,

I have a **config/settings.yml** file that looks like this:

lab_options:
  mappings_hash: {can_type: "Tumor::OncologyRun.basic_test"}

then in my model **app/models/tumor.rb** I wanted to do something like this

```
def sync_tumor_test
  Settings.lab_options.mappings_hash.to_hash[:can_type](age, demographic)
end
```

In the above case I want to call the method **Tumor::OncologyRun.basic_test** with arguments **age** and **demographics**. The method  Tumor::OncologyRun.basic_test is present in lib/tumor/oncology_run.rb and looks like this:

```
    module Tumor
     module OncologyRun
      def OncologyRun.basic_test(age, demographics)
       #code here
      end
     end
   end
```

I know that in ruby method names are strings, so how do I call this with arguments, when I am trying this from the rails console with something like **send(Settings.lab_options.mappings_hash.to_hash[:can_type](age, demographic))** I get a **NOMethod Error** any feedback is much much appreciated, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you're storing both the object name and the method call in a single string, so first you have to break them up, then use `send`, like so:

```
klass, meth = Settings.lab_options.mappings_hash.to_hash[:can_type].split('.')
klass.constantize.send(meth.to_sym, age, demographic)
```

The above should be equivelant to calling `Tumor::OncologyRun.basic_test(age, demographic)`.  The `constantize` call is necessary to convert from the name of the object into the actual ruby object.

Note - this assumes that `basic_test` is a class method on `OncologyRun`.  If it's an instance method, you'll need to call `new` first and then use the `send` call on the resultant object.